# extract integer from html according to multiple parameters with sed

Tags: html, bash, parsing, sed

First of all, let me say this:
I know regx'ing html is considered a bad approach, but if chuck norris can, why can't I? ;)
I want to parse this html page: http://pastebin.com/unAifctF
based on three parameters. i tried: (thank you pixellany)

```
sed -n  '/hebrew/{/DESPiTE/s/downloadsubtitle.php?id=/XXX/1};s/.*XXX\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

which returns 228344 instead of 228338
and i tried: (thank you doubleDown)

```
sed -nr 's/.*downloadsubtitle.php\?id\=([0-9]+).*hebrew.*DESPiTE.*/\1/p'
```

which returns 228343 instead of 228338
the expected result is 228338 because it's the first number preceded by "downloadsubtitle.php\?id\=" and followed by "hebrew" and "DESPiTE"
what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/[\x00\x01\x02]/q1;/hebrew/!b;s//\x01/;/DESPiTE/!b;s//\x02/;/downloadsubtitle.php?id=/!b;s//\x00/;s/.*\x00\([0-9]\+\)[^\x00\x01\x02]*\x01[^\x00\x01\x02]*\x02.*/\1/p' file
```

Explanantion:

- `/[\x00\x01\x02]/q1` check the line contains delimiters, if so abort with error code `1`
- `/hebrew/!b;s//\x01/` check if line contains `hebrew` if not bail out, if so translate the word `hebrew` to the single character `\x01`
- `/DESPiTE/!b;s//\x02/` check if line contains `DESPiTE` if not bail out, if so translate the word `DESPiTE` to the single character `\x02`
- `/downloadsubtitle.php?id=/!b;s//\x00/` check if line contains `downloadsubtitle.php?id=` if not bail out, if so translate the word `downloadsubtitle.php?id=` to the single character `\x00`
- `s/.*\x00\([0-9]\+\)[^\x00\x01\x02]*\x01[^\x00\x01\x02]*\x02.*/\1/p` print out the desired number.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -nE '
    @fields = split /downloadsubtitle\.php\?id=([0-9]+)/;
    for (1 .. $#fields) {
        next unless $_ % 2;
        say $fields[$_] if $fields[$_ + 1] =~ /hebrew.*DESPiTE/;
    }
' unAifctF.html
```

How does it work? It splits a line on the `downloadsubtitle.php?id=XXX`, while keeping the numbers in between. Then, it prints a number, if the string following it up to the next `downloadsubtitle...` contains `hebrew` followed by `DESPiTE`.

Comment: i want to put a variable instead of "DESPITE", like this: perl -nE '
    @fields = split /downloadsubtitle\.php\?id=([0-9]+)/;
    for (1 .. $#fields) {
        next unless $_ % 2;
        say $fields[$_] if $fields[$_ + 1] =~ /hebrew.*$var/;
    }
' unAifctF.html , i tired it but it doesn't work. do i need to escape it?

Comment: @buntuser: If the variable might contain special characters, you should quote it: `/hebrew.*\Q$var\E/`

Comment: i tried    /hebrew.*\Q$var\E/ and also-    /\Q$var1.*\Q$var\E/ both return nothing. if return to the original, i get the id (number) of course

Comment: $var will contain either letters or numbers. no special characters.

Comment: @buntuser: Yep. The single quotes in fact *interrupt* the quoted string, letting the shell to insert the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `*` is a greedy operator, so it will match as much as it can, causing it to stop not on the first possible match, but on the last possible match. Therefore, you should probably change what it tries to match. The problem is that you want it to match anything except another "downloadsubtitle.php?id=", which is difficult in `sed`. You either create a more complex sed script, or you can use a simple workaround that assumes that there will not be any `?`s between the link and the title =)

```
sed -nr 's/.*downloadsubtitle.php\?id\=([0-9]+)[^?]*hebrew[^?]*DESPiTE.*/\1/p'
```

If you want a proper script:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

: next
$! { N; b next }
s/\n//g

s/downloadsubtitle\.php?id=\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\
\1/

: loop
s/^[^\n]*\n//

h
s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/
x

s/downloadsubtitle\.php?id=\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\
\1/
/^[^\n]*hebrew[^\n]*DESPiTE/ { g; p; q }
/^[0-9]*/ b loop
```

This script starts out by loading the whole file into pattern space (ie. the working buffer). It does this in the first two lines. The first line declares a label called `next` with the `:` "command". The second line appends the next line from input into the pattern space with the `N` command and then jumps back to the `next` label, but these two commands are only executed if we haven't read the last line yet. The third line removes all newline characters.

Now, we replace the first occurrance of `downloadsubtitle\.php?id=[0-9][0-9]*` with a newline character (represented by the backslash followed by an actual new line) and the ID number.

A new label `loop` is created, and the first thing we do after it is to remove everthing up to the the first newline character (so we remove everything before the id).

Now we have a series of commands that will extract the number and store it into hold space (an auxiliary buffer). We first copy the entire pattern space into hold space using the `h` command, then remove everything after the numbers, then swap the contents of the hold and pattern space with the `x`. Now the hold space contains the number, and the pattern space was restored to its value.

To prevent the greedy search, we will place a newline character before the next occurrance of `downloadsubtitle\.php?id=[0-9][0-9]*`. We can also leave just the ID number, because the newline will indicate that we found the rest of the string.

Now comes the search part. To recap, we have the actual ID in hold space, and the first line of the pattern space is where we want to search for the text. So we use the search expression that searches, from the start of the buffer, for the strings `hebrew` and `DESPiTE` and that aren't separated from each other or from the start of the buffer by a newline. Therefore, we've searched only the first line.

If a match is found, we use `g` to get the ID from hold space, `p` to print it, and then `q` to quit.

If we don't find a match, we simply jump back to the `loop` label, and search the next occurrance. The condition before the jump is to prevent an infinite loop. If there's nothing to search, it quits.

Hope this helps =)